Parsley has white/yellow decoloration and spots
Complete beginner here. I planted a parsley 2 months ago and I left it with automatic watering for 1 month and when I came back the leaves where discolored and had some spots of yellow or white. Some leaves are completely white. I tried washing it off because I read it may be powdery mildew but the color stayed. Is it a disease or a deficiency? Probably I will keep it until it withers or get rid of it but I am interested in the diagnosis and what I did wrong so I can learn.



The leaves that have turned white looks like papery, like like it has nothing in between? Sunburnt? Not sure.

I think it is a rot, I got it sometime. Cut and put in a more sunny place (an maybe less watering).
